# Is AES solvable by reducing to SAT?

Tags: aes, brute-force-attack, complexity

Consider a known plaintext attack on AES — just so we have an actual system of equalities that we can feed to a SAT solver.

Is AES solvable in this way? In other words, will the algorithm eventually complete, producing the correct key?

After reading through [these set of slides](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csmg/2009_BCTCSWarwick_MG.pdf), I assume the answer is yes, but that it is computationally even more costly than brute force, making it impractical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is AES solvable in this way? In other words, will the algorithm eventually complete, producing the correct key?

Almost **yes**. It will produce *some* correct key — there might be more than one.

<sup>(It should quite plausibly be unique given "enough" plaintext-ciphertext samples, but this need not be the case in general.)</sup>

Generally, computing the key in a known-plaintext scenario is in $\mathbf{NP}$, hence can by definition be reduced to any $\mathbf{NP}$-complete problem such as $\mathrm{SAT}$. If this is done correctly, solving the $\mathrm{SAT}$ instance is bound to produce a correct key — but fortunately, doing so is not at all practical to the best of our current knowledge.

<sup>(If it turned out that $\mathbf P=\mathbf{NP}$, this would potentially change that picture a bit, but in that case we are doomed anyway.)</sup>

Therefore the short answer is: **Yes, but it doesn't help.**

Comment: You can quite easily show that for a few random messages there will be a single key except for very small probability. (Note that saying "unfortunately" depends on what side of the fence you sit. As cryptographers, we very much want $P\neq NP$ and more.)

Comment: @YehudaLindell That first sentence doesn't work for me with "random messages". Besides, yyyyyyy  already put that in the fine print, didn't he?

Comment: You say **unfortunately** anybody with data to protect would say **fortunately**.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Doesn't that need an additional assumption? Unless I am missing something, one can easily construct a PRP $(F_k)$ such that two distinct keys $k_1,k_2$ yield the same permutation $F_{k_1}=F_{k_2}$. Right?

Comment: If K1 and K2 both yield the same permutation, then they are the same key (so I don't care what I get). But I guess that you can build a permutation with K1 and K2 that agree on half the values, or something like that. So, maybe you are right.

Comment: Even if we had a constructive proof of P=NP, the constant factor for this problem may be millions of years.

Answer (score 2):

yyyyyyy's answer is great, and nicely points out that everything in $\mathrm{NP}$ can be reduced to an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem like $\mathrm{SAT}$, but I feel like it might leave a reader with a misconception in this particular case. Note that the problem you've pointed out (finding a key that matches some known plaintext/ciphertext pairs) is in $\mathrm{P}$, and in particular, can be solved in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time by look up table (for a fixed number of input pairs).

It turns out that questions asking about classes like $\mathrm{NP}$ and $\mathrm{NP}$-complete has essentially no traction on practical problems, where we generally deal with finite primitives, rather than infinite families of primitives. It is simply too coarse of a tool.

Comment: This answer misses the point. Of course, it is possible to brute force anything that is finite. Then, since the world is finite everything is efficient. However, computational complexity works in that it even though it is asymptotic in nature, it predicts the difficulty of working on large inputs.

Comment: @YehudaLindell The answer isn't missing the point: rather, it's pointing out that P-vs-NP isn't the right model to be using here. This is because the P-vs-NP model _does_ lead to the unreasonable conclusion that recovering a key of fixed length is, by the definitions used within that model, a constant-time operation. The model fundamentally contains the idea that fixed-sized instances are easy; pointing that out is not "missing the point."

Comment: The question does not make any assumption about the _type_ of algorithm used to solve the SAT system. It may complete in a reasonable amount of time. Whether such algorithms on SAT's exist is for another question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't agree; I think that it is missing the point. The theory informs practice here in a very fundamental way. In any case, what is important to point out is that even if $P\neq NP$, this does *not* mean that it cannot be broken. One needs much stronger assumptions than just $P\neq NP$.